# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a MySQL desde C#?

Tags: c#

estoy intentando conectarme a mi servidor alojado en Namecheap desde mi programa de C# (Estoy usando .NET framework). Estoy usando: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` para conectarme, puedo establecer una conexión sin ningún problema con mi localhost, usando Xampp, pero a la hora de conectarme a mi servidor remoto, no puedo, el error es el siguiente: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'`
Mi script es este:

```
String conString = "Server=miip;Port=mi_puerto;DATABASE=mi_database;Uid=root;Pwd=password;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        String command = "Select * From ejemplo";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        connection.Open();
```

Al ponerme en contacto con el soporte de Namecheap, me han ofrecido esto:[Este link para ayudarme](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1249/89/how-to-remotely-connect-to-a-mysql-database-located-on-our-shared-server/)
Y me han comentado que debía hacer un Tunnel. ¿Qué puedo hacer? Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: ¿Has intentado seguir las instrucciones del enlace? Me parecen bastante claras. Puedes bajarte Putty desde [este enlace](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).

Comment: Como te dice @RogerTorné, simplemente sigue las instrucciones del enlace. Luego tendrás que poner **TU IP LOCAL (localhost)** y el puerto que te indican en tu propia máquina, y eso redirigirá todo el tráfico a tu servidor remoto. Se debe hacer así porque su servidor no acepta conexiones remotas por seguridad, tal como explican en el enlace.

Comment: @RogerTorné Sí, las he seguido. Tengo putty pero lo que necesito es que se conecte mi script de C#, no el hecho de tener acceso yo al servidor. Aunque no sé si te refieres a lo mismo que yo.

Comment: @Benito-B Yo puedo entrar al servidor sin ningún problema mediante putty, pero me gustaría que pudiese distribuir mi programa a mis clientes y que ellos tuviesen también acceso a la base de datos desde el propio programa sin necesidad de putty.

Comment: Entonces deberás realizar el tunnel programáticamente, puede que con ayuda de alguna librería externa. En [este enlace](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/ssh_tunnel.asp) tienes un ejemplo.

Comment: O usar un servidor diferente donde se te permita configurar todo a tu gusto. El problema con las cosas baratas es que están muy limitadas, si planteas distribuirlo a otra gente te recomiendo que escojas un servidor un poco mejor, tal vez un VPS sobre el que tengas control total. De esa manera no tendrás nunca problemas de este tipo.

Comment: @Benito-B me parece la mejor idea jaja, ¿Tienes alguna recomendación?

Comment: @QuiqueFernandez No estoy aquí para hacer publicidad a páginas o servicios de terceros :) En google hay disponible una enorme cantidad de información sobre VPS a precios más que competitivos, dependiendo de donde vivas.